# add change language button with javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, html

My javascript code:

```
var footer = document.getElementsByTagName('footer');
for (var i = 0; i < footer.length; ++i) {
    var appendTo = footer[0].getElementsByTagName('p'); //get only the p in the first footer to select
    if(language.indexOf('nl') <= -1 && location.href.indexOf("/") >= 0 && location.href.indexOf("/en/") <= -1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < appendTo.length; ++i) {
            appendTo[0].innerHTML += '<div class="language item switch en"><a href="/en/">english</a></div>';
        }
    } else if(language.indexOf('nl') == 0 && location.href.indexOf("/en/") >= 0 ) {
        for (var i = 0; i < appendTo.length; ++i) {
            appendTo[0].innerHTML += '<div class="language item switch nl"><a href="/">nederlands</a></div>';
        }
    } else {}
}
```

I don't get any console errors. I want to add a 'change language' button when a user is not on the correct language site. Where did I go wrong in my code?

Comment: console.log("is your friend?");

Comment: Do you have a fiddle at all?  If you can make one, i will look into it

Comment: @Fallenreaper here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ecsuZ/1/

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: language is not defined

Comment: Maybe it is handy when I say I call the script in the head tag

Comment: well, i have no idea what language is, it looks like it is scanning through language, to find an occurance of "nl".  I feel that the fiddle is incomplete.   If you can adjust it, then we can get closer to an answer

Comment: @Fallenreaper I can't get closer in a fiddle, the page is here: http://www.sakesalverda.nl/ and than it is the core.js

Comment: @Fallenreaper I have found the problem, I had to load the script when the dom was ready.

Comment: ahhh, ok.  I also found this for you:  `var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
language = language.split("-");`

Comment: np.  Have a great day Sake

Answer (score 0):

the variable `language` isn't defined in your function.  If you declare it, it seems to work fine.

```
var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
language = language.split("-");
    var footer = document.getElementsByTagName('footer');
    for (var i = 0; i < footer.length; ++i) {
        var appendTo = footer[0].getElementsByTagName('p'); //get only the p in the first footer to select
        if(language.indexOf('nl') <= -1 && location.href.indexOf("/") >= 0 && location.href.indexOf("/en/") <= -1) {
            for (var i = 0; i < appendTo.length; ++i) {
                appendTo[0].innerHTML += '<div class="language item switch en"><a href="/en/">english</a></div>';
            }
        } else if(language.indexOf('nl') == 0 && location.href.indexOf("/en/") >= 0 ) {
            for (var i = 0; i < appendTo.length; ++i) {
                appendTo[0].innerHTML += '<div class="language item switch nl"><a href="/">nederlands</a></div>';
            }
        } else {}
    }
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ecsuZ/2/

Comment: its defined in his website, in /js/core.js, which is why i was confused at first.

Comment: Didn't even notice the updated comment thread.  Ah well - looks like we were both heading to the same answer.